# Unable to deploy HDP via Ambari 2.2.1.1

Tags: hadoop, hortonworks-data-platform, ambari

I can't deploy HDP stack(hdfs, yarn, spark .etc) via Ambari 2.2.1.1. I got this error:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/lib/ambari-agent/cache/stacks/HDP/2.0.6/hooks/before-ANY/scripts/hook.py", line 35, in 
    BeforeAnyHook().execute()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/resource_management/libraries/script/script.py", line 219, in execute
    method(env)
  File "/var/lib/ambari-agent/cache/stacks/HDP/2.0.6/hooks/before-ANY/scripts/hook.py", line 29, in hook
    setup_users()
  File "/var/lib/ambari-agent/cache/stacks/HDP/2.0.6/hooks/before-ANY/scripts/shared_initialization.py", line 43, in setup_users
    fetch_nonlocal_groups = params.fetch_nonlocal_groups
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/resource_management/core/base.py", line 149, in **init**
    self.arguments[key] = arg.validate(value)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/resource_management/core/base.py", line 56, in validate
    if not value in (True, False):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/resource_management/libraries/script/config_dictionary.py", line 81, in **getattr**
    raise Fail("Configuration parameter '" + self.name + "' was not found in configurations dictionary!")
**resource_management.core.exceptions.Fail: Configuration parameter 'fetch_nonlocal_groups' was not found in configurations dictionary!**
Error: Error: Unable to run the custom hook script ['/usr/bin/python', '/var/lib/ambari-agent/cache/stacks/HDP/2.0.6/hooks/before-ANY/scripts/hook.py', 'ANY', '/var/lib/ambari-agent/data/command-387.json', '/var/lib/ambari-agent/cache/stacks/HDP/2.0.6/hooks/before-ANY', '/var/lib/ambari-agent/data/structured-out-387.json', 'INFO', '/var/lib/ambari-agent/tmp']

Did someone see this error before? Thanks in advance!